# How to represent 6 integer key better than as indices to a 6-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, data-structures, key, memoization

In my program, a state can be uniquely identified by six integers. Each integer, `i` satisfies `0 <= i <= 10` and each state has an associated value. I am currently using a 6-dimensional array to keep track of each states value. I am storing the state values in an array like so `state[11][11][11][11][11][11][11]`, where each value has the 6 integers as a key. However, this array would be very sparse, as I only visit a small number of possible states. Is there a better way to represent the key for the value of a state?

Comment: Maybe [`std::map<key-type, value-type>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [`std::unordered_map<key-type, value-type>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

Comment: if you choose a better way to store the value, you can also use a better representation for the key. However, there is too little context. Why do you think you need a 6-dimensional array?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to avoid using 6 different integer indices? Are you looking for a way to have, say, a class State that can somehow index your array? You added the memoisation tag, so are you building code that needs to push/pop the state to/from a stack?

Comment: Well the 6-dimensional array would be very sparse, as I only visit a small number of possible states. I suppose an `unordered_map` with a vector containing the six digits could work.

Comment: Each integer can be stored in 4 bits, 6*4 bits would fit in a 32-bit integer a 32-bit integer key into a map would probably work depending on your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to have a value in every state you can get away with using a map

Concept code, totally untested.

```
constexpr int dimension = 6;
using KeyType = std::array<char, dimension>;
int32_t Key(const & KeyType keys) {
  int32_t res = 0;
  for (auto key : keys) {
    res <<= 4;
    res += key;
  }
  return res;
}

void Key2Array(int32_t keyValue, KeyType& keys) {
  int idx = dimension-1;
  for (auto& key : keys) {
    keys[idx--] = keyValue&0x16;
    keyValue >>= 4;
  }
}

std::map<int32_t, value> states;

states[Key({1,2,3,4,5,6}] = 42;

KeyType key;
Key2Array(0x123456, key);
```

Comment: How would I from the key extract the initial 6 integers? @Surt

Comment: @TomFinet Basically reverse the Key metode.